# C++ GDI+ Image class: how to acess private member declared in class 'Gdipus::Image' C2248

Tags: c++, image, gdi+

I tried to read my PNG image file to create a sprite from it. I used this code for reading and drawing images:

```
wchar_t filename = L'bunny.png';
wchar_t* path2 = &filename;

Image image = Image(path2, false);

Image* pImage = &image;

Graphics graphics(pImage);

graphics.DrawImage(pImage, 10, 60);
```

But compiler show me:

> error C2248. 'Gdiplus::Image::Image': cannot access private member declared in class 'Gdiplus::Image'

I tried to use the constructor from the public section of the Image class, but it was recognized like a constructor from the private section.

```
Image image = Image(IN path2, false);
```

Can somebody show me piece of code which will work in this situation, please?

Comment: Whoah there... firstly, `filename` is _NOT_ what you think, and therefore neither is `path2`.

Comment: `const wchar_t *filename = L"bunny.png";` and pass it to the constructor. Note the double quotes. You should have received a warning `warning C4066: characters beyond first in wide-character constant ignored` and paid attention to it. If you didn't you should turn your warning level up.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like overload resolution is taking over here because you are not supplying the correct types to the constructor. Notably `false` is not of type `BOOL`. It is of type `bool`. You should have used `FALSE`.

While `BOOL` is an integer type, and `bool` is implicitly convertible to `int`, this may be sufficient to confuse the compiler. The overload resolution system may preferentially choose a private constructor with a better-matching signature before even trying to convert the `bool`.

The constructor you actually wanted is:

```
Image(
    IN const WCHAR* filename,
    IN BOOL useEmbeddedColorManagement = FALSE
);
```

You can therefore simply do this (noting that the second parameter already defaults to FALSE):

```
Image image(L"bunny.png");
```

If you want to store the path in a variable, it's already been pointed out in the comments section that you've done it the wrong way. You tried to use a multi-value character literal, then treat that as a NUL-terminated string. This is highly incorrect.

Instead, use `const WCHAR*` or simply `LPCWSTR` for short:

```
LPCWSTR path = L"bunny.png";
Image image(path);
```

Comment: Ultimately, your solution is correctly, but your initial assumption is wrong. The problem has nothing to do with overload resolution at all.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are encountering is due to the incorrect usage of the Gdiplus::Image class constructor. The constructor expects a pointer to a `const WCHAR` as the first parameter, but you are providing a pointer to a single `wchar_t`. Also, there is no second parameter in the constructor.

Here's the corrected code:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <gdiplus.h>
using namespace Gdiplus;

int main() {
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);

    const WCHAR* filename = L"bunny.png"; // use a const WCHAR pointer

    Image image(filename); // no second parameter

    // Continue with the rest of your drawing code

    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you should initialize Gdiplus before using it and shut it down when you're done.

Comment: I believe `WCHAR` is just a typedef or `#define` for `wchar_t`, it shouldn't matter which you use.

Comment: Thank you very much!
tell me please, how can I check that bunny.png is already readed and inside the memory?
I see this 0x000001b4b1ad22a0 inside nativeImage slot while debugging, and try to put getter inside the code (like this image.GetRawFormat(***)), but cannot understand how to write it correctly.

Comment: @AmirhaniAllhyari ultimately, your solution is correct, but pretty much everything you said in your 1st paragraph is wrong. `WCHAR` is indeed just an alias for `wchar_t`. The constructor takes a `const wchar_t*` but is being passed a `wchar_t*`, which is perfectly OK because the latter is implicitly convertible to the former (obviously, passing a pointer to a single `wchar_t` is wrong, but that becomes a runtime error, not a compile-time error). And yes, the constructor does have a 2nd parameter, actually. It just has a default value declared.

Comment: I try tis code and it generate exeption while I try to continue with drawing code:
Graphics graphics(&image); 
 graphics.DrawImage(&image, 10, 60);

 GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);

 

return 0;
};
Exeption msg:
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFD6C3662BA (GdiPlus.dll) inFileName.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000002A64FA23410.

Comment: @TimofeyKalakutsky You do realize that you are trying to draw the PNG image onto itself, don't you? To get a `Graphics` object for drawing on a window, use the `Graphics` constructor that takes an `HWND` or `HDC`, or use `Graphics::FromHWND()` or `Graphics::FromHDC()` instead

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you :)
but here provided the same example, or not?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-loading-and-displaying-bitmaps-use?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: @TimofeyKalakutsky Nowhere in those examples does it show the `Graphic` object being created from the same `Image` that is then being drawn onto the `Graphic`, as you are doing. Your AV is because the `Image` is being written to while it is being read from. Use a different target for the `Graphic` to draw onto.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you are creating a temporary `Image` and copying it to another `Image`. The copy constructor is private, because `Image` can't be copied.

You must be using a pre-C++17 compiler, because C++17 and later would have eliminated the temporary for you. So, you will have to simply get rid it yourself, ie change this:

```
Image image = Image(path2, false);
```

To this instead:

```
Image image(path2, false);
// or: Image image(path2);
```

Also, your `filename` and `path` variables are being setup wrong. They should be more like this instead:

```
const wchar_t* filename = L"bunny.png";
wchar_t* path2 = filename;
```

Lastly, you don't need so many redundant local variables to begin with:

```
Image image(L"bunny.png");
Graphics graphics(&image);
graphics.DrawImage(&image, 10, 60);
```

That being said, why are you drawing a PNG onto itself? You mentioned in a comment that you don't know how to link a `Graphic` object to a window. `Graphic` has constructors which take an `HWND` or `HDC` for output. It also has static `FromHWND()` and `FromHDC()` methods, too.